# Complex Critical points of a Real Valued function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, systems-of-equations, extreme-value-analysis

Assume that the function is $f:\mathbb{R}²\to\mathbb{R}³$

**Exercise: Find and classify the crititcal points of the function**
\begin{equation*}
f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{2+x^4+y^4}
\end{equation*}

**Attempt**
Find $f'(x,y)$ og $f''(x,y)$:

\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{y(2+x^4+y^4)-4x^4y}{(2+x^4+y^4)^2}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{x(2+x^4+y^4)-4y^4x}{(2+x^4+y^4)^2}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}=-\frac{20yx^3}{(x^4+y^4+2)^2}+\frac{32x^7y}{(x^4+y^4+2)^3}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}=-\frac{20y^3x}{(x^4+y^4+2)^2}+\frac{32xy^7}{(x^4+y^4+2)^3}
\end{equation*}

For $0=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ we find

\begin{equation*}
 \frac{y(2+x^4+y^4)-4x^4y}{(2+x^4+y^4)^2}=\frac{x(2+x^4+y^4)-4y^4x}{(2+x^4+y^4)^2}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
 y\left((2+x^4+y^4)-4x^4\right)=x\left((2+x^4+y^4)-4y^4\right)
\end{equation*}
A solution is therefore $x=y=0$

We would like to search for any other solutions within the parathesis

\begin{equation*}
 \begin{cases}
  0=2+x^4+y^4-4x^4y\\
  0=2+x^4+y^4-4y^4x
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Gives:
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{cases}
  0=-4x^4y\\
  0=-4y^4x
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

**Problem:**
I know that there is for sure complex solutions to the system of equations. Although, since we are in the reals I have problems finding out weither:

1. Since we are in the reals, we forget about the FTA, and then just take the solutions we can find without complex numbers
2. There is something that I've simply missed? Although i have checked with WolframAlpha and used my common sense.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the stated domain is $\Bbb R^2$, you must ignore complex solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have gone astray in several ways here. What you are looking for is points where both $\frac {\partial f}{\partial x} = 0$ and $\frac {\partial f}{\partial y} = 0$, but you've gotten distracted by where $\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}  = \frac {\partial f}{\partial y}$, which indeed is necessary, but is not sufficient.

The set of equations you need to solve is $$\frac{y(2+x^4+y^4)-4x^4y}{(2+x^4+y^4)^2} = 0\\\frac{x(2+x^4+y^4)-4y^4x}{(2+x^4+y^4)^2} = 0$$
Multiplying through by the denominators, this is $$y(2+x^4+y^4)-4x^4y = 0\\x(2+x^4+y^4)-4y^4x = 0$$
If we let $x = 0$, then the system easily solves to $y = 0$, and vice versa. Since you've already found the $(0,0)$ solution, we can assume that both $x \ne 0, y\ne 0$ and so can divide them out, leaving

$$2-3x^4+y^4 = 0\\2+x^4-3y^4 = 0$$
This system is easy to solve to get $x^4 = 1, y^4 = 1$, which gives $$x = \pm 1, y = \pm 1$$

So there are 5 critical points in total.

Comment: This is brilliant - thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Well, thank you for the compliment, but it actually is just the straightforward way to solve for critical points (though this particular problem offered a convenient shortcut to a solution). You would have found it yourself, except for being accidently sidetracked by $\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}  = \frac {\partial f}{\partial y}$.

Comment: Agreed - although now, we emphasized that $f_1(x,y)=0=f_2(x,y)$, somewhat is not correct anymore if we just write (as I did) $f_1(x,y)=f_2(x,y)$ then this assumption about being equal to zero is somewhat not used anymore - correct?

Comment: I cannot make sense of that. $f_1(x,y)=f_2(x,y)$ is correct. It just doesn't tell the whole story ("necessary, but not sufficient"). What is important is that the value both posess is zero. That $f_1(x,y) = 0$ and $f_2(x,y) = 0$ is not an assumption. It is the definition of "critical point". Since you are looking for critical points, it is the tool you must use to recognize them.